# Can operator return a function?

Tags: haskell

I learn Haskell.

This is not *an operator*, because an operator must to have *two* parameters:

```
(###) :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
(###) a b c = a + b + c
```

But what about this case:

```
(###) :: Int -> Int -> (Int -> Int)
(###) a b = \c -> a + b + c
```

This function has two parameters, but returns a function... Is it an *operator* now? I think it is not an operator still, because second variant is partial applied first. But I am not sure I am right. Can operator return a function?

Comment: Have you tried running your code to see what happens? Both should work just fine. You can call them as e.g. `(10 ### 20) 30`.

Comment: I know, both works fine. But I asked is the second variant an operator or it is a function? Any operator is a function, but not any function is an operator.

Comment: Both versions of the function are equivalent. There is no difference.

Comment: I know they does the same. But what about their "status"? They both are not operators?

Comment: They're both operators when used in infix position (at least that is the terminology the Haskell Report uses).

Comment: @Bush After all this dialogue, I've decided to provide another, hopefully exhaustive, reply to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28106953/what-is-the-operator-word-definition

Comment: What hinges on whether you call this an operator or not? (Why should we care whether it is an operator?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no rule that says an operator has to have two parameters and in fact, semantically all functions in Haskell only ever take a single parameter. Your two examples are exactly identical as the type `Int -> Int -> Int -> Int` is implicitly bracketed as `Int -> (Int -> (Int -> Int))`.

You can use your operator like this

```
(1 ### 2) 3
```

or

```
1 ### 2 $ 3
```

Comment: I asked about parameters count here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28106953/what-is-the-operator-word-definition As I see through the comments - operator must to have two parameters. Am I mistaken?

Comment: You want to say function is an operator when it has name with ascSymbol symbols **and not two parameters even**?

Comment: I have already said in the comments of the other question that this assumption is wrong. shang is right.

Comment: Yes, that's because `###` *is* an operator. The report states (as is quoted correctly in the other question) that the criterion for calling something an operator is whether it can syntactically be applied in infix position. This is true for `###`. It doesn't matter "how many arguments it has" or "what its return type is".